# Can you use Scrapy to detect new content or pages on a website?

Tags: python, scrapy

Can you run scrapy constantly and detect new pages or new content added to a page?

You can use a cronjob to do a complete site scan every few hours, but what if you wanted to capture changes or additions as they happen?

Comment: It's possible, yes. Wouldn't really need scrapy. You'll probably be IP banned relatively quickly if you tried it though. If you need data from somewhere the polite thing to do is to ask the site owner; they'll either give it to you for free, charge you for it or refuse altogether.

Comment: I guess we are bound by Http requests and responses. In that case we could diff the html on the index pages, with previous scrapes and then only scan new content. But that is not a communication session for instant recognition of changes, like web sockets

Comment: What if the site has an rss feed...constantly poll the feed?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you could use scrapy, to answer your question. However, http headers contain a LastModified/ContentLength field that you can retrieve without a GET call. Instead, issue a HEAD call and parse that field to see if the ContentLength or LastModified has changed since your last GET.

References:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

https://ochronus.com/http-head-request-good-uses/